# Ubuntu Login Freeze

Tags: login, freeze

I haven't used Ubuntu in a couple months and just now did the updates. In doing so I cannot get passed the login screen. I can move my mouse but am unable to type. I've looked this issue up and saw a reboot option except holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> didn't bring up advanced options and doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> garners no results. What should I do and when?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to reinstall Ubuntu as that was how I fixed the same problem on my own computer.